# Find all rooted subgraphs of a DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, enumeration, dag

I searched the exchange and couldn't seem to find an answer to this.

I am trying to find an algorithm that, given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) $G = (N,E)$ with a single root node $r\in N$, finds *all* connected subgraphs $G_i\subseteq G$ that contain r.

---

**What I've attempted so far**

Consider the following DAG,

[image]

To start, we have the graph:

$(\{1\},\varnothing)$

From the root, we should do a one-step search, including $m$ nodes, where $m$ ranges from $1$ to the number of children (of the root), in each subgraph. That is, the next set of subgraphs are:

$(\{1,2\},\{(1,2)\})$

$(\{1,3\},\{(1,3)\})$

$(\{1,4\},\{(1,4)\})$

$(\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2),(1,3)\})$

$(\{1,2,4\},\{(1,2),(1,4)\})$

$(\{1,3,4\},\{(1,3),(1,4)\})$

$(\{1,2,3,4\},\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)\})$

For *each* one of the above subgraphs, should we just do another one-step search?

---

**Questions**

Does anyone know of a better algorithm for recursively counting all of the subgraphs? I'm now aware that there is likely no polynomial-time algorithm (thanks to Raphael's comment) and such an algorithm may have exponential complexity in the worst-case.

Comment: Since there may be exponentially many such graphs, probably not. It may be more useful to ask about an iterator-style enumeration and restrict the time available to produce the next output.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?